# Pandas groupby apply (nested) slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 'category' and 'number' columns. I want to create a new column 'avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5' which is calculated after grouping by 'category' and averaging highest 2 values from the previous 5 rows' number values, excluding the current row.

```
np.random.seed(123)
n_rows = 10000
data = {'category': np.random.randint(1, 1000, n_rows), 'number': np.random.randint(1, n_rows, n_rows)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

%timeit df['avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5'] = df.groupby('category')['number'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(5, min_periods=0).apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y).nlargest(2).mean()))

df = df[df['category'] == df['category'].values[0]]
df
```

out:
4.55 s ± 34.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
       category        number   avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5
0           511         4179    NaN
392         511         2878    4179.0
1292        511         5834    3528.5
1350        511         1054    5006.5
1639        511         8673    5006.5
3145        511         8506    7253.5
4176        511         947     8589.5
4471        511         151     8589.5
4735        511         5326    8589.5
4965        511         4827    8589.5
5046        511         9792    6916.0
5316        511         3772    7559.0
5535        511         1095    7559.0
5722        511         5619    7559.0
5732        511         700     7705.5
6825        511         1156    7705.5
6877        511         7240    4695.5
8100        511         2381    6429.5
8398        511         2376    6429.5
```

this operation takes 36 seconds with 10k rows and 1k categories. When I try this in 1m+ rows dataframe it takes around 8 minutes. I think there should be a faster way for what I'm trying to do, and I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Kindly create a small dataframe of 5 to 10 rows , with the expected output dataframe

Comment: With your parameters 1M+ and 1000 categories ```Method 2``` I proposed is 9.4% faster, so you earn around 50 seconds on 8 mn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a different solution is to use Polars (https://www.pola.rs/) instead of Pandas.

In my tests, the Pandas function takes 5.33 seconds, while the Polars function takes 30.1 ms. Thus 178 times faster.

You can install Polars with `pip install polars`

Here is the function:

```
import polars as pl

# convert the dataframe to Polars
df_polars = pl.from_pandas(df)

# run the calculation
df_polars_result = df_polars.with_columns(
        pl.lit(1).alias('ones')
    ).with_columns(
        i = pl.col('ones').cumsum().over('category').cast(pl.Int32),
        num_shifted = pl.col('number').shift(1).over('category')
        ) \
    .groupby_rolling(index_column = 'i', period='5i', by='category').agg(
        pl.last('number'),    
        avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5 = 
            pl.col('num_shifted').sort(descending=True).slice(0,2).mean()
)
30.1 ms ± 6.37 ms per loop

# Convert back to Pandas if needed
df_pandas_result = df_polars_result.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True)


# Example of the result
┌──────────┬─────┬────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ category ┆ i   ┆ number ┆ avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5 │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---                          │
│ i64      ┆ i32 ┆ i64    ┆ f64                          │
╞══════════╪═════╪════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│ 511      ┆ 1   ┆ 4179   ┆ null                         │
│ 511      ┆ 2   ┆ 2878   ┆ 4179.0                       │
│ 511      ┆ 3   ┆ 5834   ┆ 3528.5                       │
│ 511      ┆ 4   ┆ 1054   ┆ 5006.5                       │
│ ...      ┆ ... ┆ ...    ┆ ...                          │
│ 511      ┆ 16  ┆ 1156   ┆ 7705.5                       │
│ 511      ┆ 17  ┆ 7240   ┆ 4695.5                       │
│ 511      ┆ 18  ┆ 2381   ┆ 6429.5                       │
│ 511      ┆ 19  ┆ 2376   ┆ 6429.5                       │
└──────────┴─────┴────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your sample**

```py
import time

start = time.time()
df['avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5'] = df.groupby('category')['number'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(5, min_periods=0).apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y).nlargest(2).mean()))
end = time.time()
```

```
>>> end-start
1.6836352348327637
```

**Speed improvement**

```py
start = time.time()
df['avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5'] = \
( df.groupby('category')['number']
    .apply(lambda s: s.shift(1).rolling(5, min_periods=0).agg( lambda s: s.nlargest(2).mean() ))
  )
end = time.time()
```

```
>>> end-start
1.623293399810791
```

Speed improvement is `3.7%` compared to the sample.

With the chosen sample we can't really see the efficiency of the `agg` function compared to the `apply` function.
If, on the other hand, we reduce the number of categories to 10 and transfer more lines to be processed accordingly to the `agg` function, we realize that the change is very significant.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(123)
n_rows = 10000
data = {'category': np.random.randint(1, 10, n_rows), 'number': np.random.randint(1, n_rows, n_rows)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

start = time.time()
df['avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5'] = df.groupby('category')['number'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(5, min_periods=0).apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y).nlargest(2).mean()))
end = time.time()

print("First method", end-start)

start = time.time()
df['avg_of_largest_2_from_prev_5'] = \
( df.groupby('category')['number']
    .apply(lambda s: s.shift(1).rolling(5, min_periods=0).agg( lambda s: s.nlargest(2).mean() ))
  )
end = time.time()
print("Second method", end-start)

First method 1.420635461807251
Second method 1.339367151260376
```

```
First method 1.420635461807251
Second method 1.339367151260376
```

Improvement is `6%` in this case

And now, I test the following parameters :

```
n_rows = 1000000
data = {'category': np.random.randint(1, 10, n_rows)...
```

and get those results with an improvement of `9.5%` :

```
First method 139.25211119651794
Second method 127.48456478118896
```

**Conclusion**

The more data you have and the less categories you have, the more the second method is significantly performant

Comment: when we go for the 1m+ rows in data, categories also go up to 10k+. It looks like agg is faster than apply even tho it is very small. I appreciate the help